# Positioning and restriction trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have an image.  I want that image to be able to move. That works fine, but now I want these blocks to move as well.  The only thing is that I cannot get the `div`s to stop overrunning the `img`.
What I mean is that the `div` blocks are positioned nearly right on top of the `img` when the page loads.  I want them to be positioned farther right on the page.
I also need to know how to limit the space to where the `img` can move.  If you can help me with that I would be grateful.

## HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Moving Mario</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
          <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
            <div id='div1' class='divs'></div>
            <div id='div2' class='divs'></div>
            <div id ='div3' class='divs'></div>
            <div id ='div4' class='divs'></div>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
```

## jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("It Worked");
  console.log('jquery active')
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
      console.log(key);
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
                $('img').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
                $('img').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            // Down Arrow Pressed
            case 40:
                $('img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

## CSS Code

```
img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:20px;
}
#div1 {
    background-color:yellow
}
#div2 {
    background-color:green;
}
#div3 {
    background-color:blue;

}
#div4 {
    background-color:red;
}
html {
    background-color: black;
}
.divs {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

I am using the code editor ATOM for this project.

Comment: What do you mean by moving image? How blocks must be moved? Img is positioned absolutely, so img goes from common flow where divs are. In other words it doesn't matter for divs where image is positioned, because they have inline-block position.

Comment: The `img` moves when the arrow keys are pushed, but when the page loads the blocks are underneath the `img` already.  I want them to be moved away from the image, so that I can make him move in between them. @victork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is above divs because of it's absolute postioin. Remove it. And instead of 'left' property of keydown handlers type 'padding-left' and so on.  See example (click on result pane and press right arrow key) http://jsfiddle.net/x3vagg32/

```
img {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
/*position: relative;*/
margin:20px;
}

$('img').animate({'padding-left': "+=10px"}, 'fast');
```

But I really cannot understand what the desired result is.

**UPDATE**

First you wrote that you wanted blocks to be moved, but now you want them to be static. If so, I think you should set *position:ablsolute* for all elements, that take part in your game. Set appropriate left and top not only for image but also for all blocks. Every time image is moved you should ckeck it's coordinates, so you can understand if your image moves over one of the blocks.

Or may be better to use some other technique for your game. For example, canvas.

Comment: I don't want him to push blocks,  eventually I want him to be able to move around these blocks and reset the game if he hits into one of them.  What exactly do each of your changes affect?

Answer (score 0):

First off put a div around your image to stop the other divs from over-running it.

Comment: how do i make it so the divs are separated more?

Comment: So the divs are separated more? I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you a trying to add space inbetween the divs add a margin to each of your divs. OR if you are trying to add in more spacing under the img. Put the img in a div as I suggested and add a margin-bottom: 50px; or whatever space you need.